# Playwright not replaying requests

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I have the following playwright test which is recording/replaying a request:

**NOT WORKING**

```
test('replay test', async ({page}) => {

    await page.routeFromHAR('playwright/har/har.zip', {
        update: false,
        url: '**/Time/**'
    });

    const dt = await page.request.get('https://timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone?timeZone=Europe/Zurich')

    // print out recorded/replayed datetime
    console.log((await dt.json()).dateTime)

});
```

if this test runs and the recording is enabled with `update: true` then the request ist recorded correctly. But after disabling the recording with `update: false` the recorded stub is **not** replayed.

But if i change the example to the following code, which uses just `page.goto` everything is working as expected.

**WORKING**

```
test('replay test', async ({page}) => {

    await page.routeFromHAR('playwright/har/har.zip', {
        update: false,
        url: '**/Time/**'
    });

    const dt = await page.goto('https://timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone?timeZone=Europe/Zurich')

    // print out recorded/replayed datetime
    console.log((await dt.json()).dateTime)

});
```

Why are the requests with `page.request.get`recorded but not replayed?

PS: In my real test i have some `page.request.put` and `page.request.post` requests i need to record. And the behaviour is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this i a known Bug in Playwright.
There is already an existing issue: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/22869

If you have the same problem, it would be nice to let them know and comment/subscribe to the issue.